# Why don't the hovercrafts have weapons against the Sentinels?

Tags: the-matrix

I'm watching the Matrix again, and I'm at the point where Sentinels are attacking the Nebuchadnezzar. They're preparing to use the EMP, and they've stated before that it's their only weapon, but why? They have the lightning rifles; is there any (in-universe) reason why they couldn't scale them up and/or mount them on turrets?

Comment: Not in canon, but random guess: Sentinels seem to swarm and exist in HUGE numbers, so any weapon other than "run the hell away" or "fry ALL of them in immediate vicinity so they don't pursue you and then run away" would be tactically inadvisable.

Comment: There's no point. You can't outrun them..

Comment: With the huge numbers, you still run into the problem of a few holding back past EMP range; wouldn't it make *more* sense to have weapons that could fire multiple times rather than an EMP, which IRL is one-shot and in-universe at least takes time to charge, even if it can fire multiple times?

Comment: They have turrets that unload millions of bullets. At least 4 of em. In Final Flight of the Osiris the ship managed to survive a while thanks to them

Comment: Yeah, just got to that part myself. Should I edit to "why doesn't the Nebuchadnezzar use its turrets?"

Comment: I think the fact that they were 4 crew down, 2 indisposed, leaving just Trinity and Morpheus as free hands, is highly relevant here.  Also, they had to stay put to keep up their connection, and if they're a sitting duck the EMP might be the better option.

Comment: Post that as an answer if you want

Comment: I agree with @DVK. Outfitting the ship would arguably make it slower in it's attempt to outrun the Sentinels and even when you would take out several hundred, your hovercraft will be still full of mechanical eels.

Comment: That’s only *one* of all the inconsistencies between the first movie and the sequels. At the time when only the first movie existed, these ships did not have gun turrets. I suppose, at this time the idea was simply that the sentinels can’t be harmed by guns. That’s how I interpreted it when I saw the movie the first time. Now that the sequels and franchises contradict it, every explanation is just retcon’ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zion's hoverships (at least some of them) *do* have gun turrets which can be used against Sentinels. For example, the [*Osiris*](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Osiris) is seen using them in the *Animatrix* short [*The Final Flight of the Osiris*](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Flight_of_the_Osiris).<sup>1</sup> Similarly, in *The Matrix Revolutions* the [*Mjolnir* ("The Hammer")](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir) is seen using them to fight off Sentinels as Niobe piloted it to Zion's Dock.

Still, as you noted, the *Nebuchadnezzar* never used them in *The Matrix* and Trinity says that the EMP is their only weapon against the Sentinels:

> Electromagnetic pulse. Disables any electrical system in the blast radius. It's the only weapon we have against the machines.

There are nonetheless several possible explanations for Trinity's statement.

First of all, in the scene you mention there was no one available to operate the gun turrets, assuming the *Nebuchadnezzar* even had any. There were only four crew members on the ship at the time, and all were busy: Neo was still in the Matrix, Tank was acting as Neo's operator to get him out of the Matrix, Trinity was talking into Neo's ear and telling him that he is The One, and Morpheus was preparing to use the EMP. The only one who might have been able to operate the gun turret was Morpheus, but the EMP is much more effective against so many Sentinels and he wouldn't have been able to detonate the EMP if he was in the gun turret.

Even so, the *Nebuchadnezzar* probably did not have any gun turrets. It would be difficult to explain how Trinity's statement could be true if it did, and the fact that no one used them suggests that they didn't exist. There are at least two possible explanations why other hoverships are seen with gun turrets but not the *Nebuchadnezzar*:

1. The other instances in which hoverships are seen using gun turrets occur later in the war against the machines. **It is possible that Zion's hoverships were not outfitted with gun turrets until after the events of *The Matrix*.**
2. There is considerable variation in Zion's hoverships -- they all look noticeably different and have different advantages and disadvantages. For example, the *Logos* is the smallest and the *Mjolnir* is the largest -- this is noted in *The Matrix Revolutions* when Niobe (Zion's best hovership pilot, who normally captains the small *Logos*) managed to pilot the large *Mjolnir* through a small mechanical line while escaping Sentinels. Another difference is that the hoverships were not constructed at the same time, and the [*Nebuchadnezzar* is the oldest known hovership in the fleet (built in 2069).](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Nebuchadnezzar)<sup>2</sup> The [*Osiris* was built in 2079](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Osiris), the [*Logos* was built in 2101](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Logos), the [*Vigilant* was built in 2106](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Vigilant), and the [*Mjolnir* was built in 2111](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir). **The *Nebuchadnezzar* may not have had gun turrets because it was one of (if not the) oldest hoverships.** Zion may not have discovered how to attach gun turrets until after the *Nebuchadnezzar* was built, and/or Zion may have upgraded the newer (and possibly better) hoverships with gun turrets first.

(Out-of-universe, the answer is probably that the Wachowskis hadn't thought of gun turrets when they made *The Matrix*, but added them when they made the sequels.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There's too much action to get a good screenshot, but you can watch the short here:

The gun turrets can be seen at about 6:20.

<sup>2</sup>The Matrix Wiki helpfully has the known hovership construction dates. These dates can be seen in the films on the ships' cores -- the inscription includes a Bible verse and the year of construction.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the world outside the Matrix are figures of an underdeveloped world, opposed to the "first world" inside the Matrix.  That is very clear when you see the food and dishes.  The third world sometimes you have some resources, but that does not mean you can use them indiscriminatedly. The scarcity of weapons can make you built a ship with minimum resources, and left the heavy weapons to defend your city.

In short, I think is a choice.  If you have to choose between defend your home or your car, maybe you choose to defend your home.